# EKS Blue Green Deployments

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, high-availability, blue-green-deployment

Currently we’re running the loads on ECS where AWS provides OOB solution for Blue Green and canary deployments using code deploy, Right we’re in a process of migrating  the applications EKS, Is there a process defined by AWS for doing the Blue green deployments on EKS, can you please post some documents for reference?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some relevant documentations  regarding Blue green deployments on EKS in AWS,hope this helps you.

https://cicd-pipeline-cdk-eks-bluegreen.workshop.aws/en/ecsbg.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/create-a-pipeline-with-canary-deployments-for-amazon-eks-with-aws-app-mesh/